# Is it ok to completely rewrite an existing question through edits?

Tags: discussion

[Does my anonymity depend on the number of Tor users around me?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/203) currently reads:

> In what manner is risk of loss of a Tor user's anonymity affected by the geographic density of surrounding Tor users?
>
> In other words, when people use Tor in an area of the world in which the rate of Tor usage is relatively high, are they at increased or decreased risk of the unmasking of their identities compared to those people using Tor in an area with relatively low Tor usage, specifically as a result of the increased density?

I think the question itself is a good one, it's just that the way it's phrased might deter answers.

Is it preferable to more or less re-write it entirely through edits, or is this better done as a new question?

Maybe something like this:

> Does my anonymity depend on the number of Tor users around me?
>
> In other words, if there are a lot of Tor users in my part of the world, do I get better or worse anonymity out of Tor compared to somebody using it in an area with few Tor users?
>
> Does the answer differ if we replace "part of the world" with other meanings of community, like particular online groups or factions?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, that is ok, if your edit doesn't change orginal meaning of the post.** You can expand shortcuts, add links, pictures, fix grammar or formatting, use other words to tell about problem, but you cannot change primary (OP's) sense of the question, because then your edit can be rollbacked or denied by reviewer ("Edit changes original meaning of post").